# How to create a draw.io shapes in mxGraph?

Tags: bpmn, mxgraph, draw.io

I've to create the following draw.io BPM shapes in mxGrpah using JavaScript.

[image: BPMN Gateways Shapes]

Answer (score 0):

maybe some of the links will help you:
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxPoint-js.html
https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000052874-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-

draw.io is an open-source project so check the following link also: 
https://github.com/jgraph/drawio

Regards,